# Outsystems - How to use ExternalSite with header block

Tags: outsystems

I have been trying to get the ExternalSite to load with the header block.
I have noted when the ExternalSite is used it keeps the site in the app. So it should be possible to load it with the app header block right?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean? Is it that you would like the OutSystems application header (with the Menu etc) to remain as you jump to an external site? ExternalSite redirects the browser completely to the given URL so that won't work unless the target URL happens to itself have the same header.

Comment: Hi  Miguel Seabra Melo I found out that this si not possible but let me Elaborate, so if anybody else sit with the same question.

In outsystems there is the possibility to use the ExternalSite which means that it will redirect to the externalSite, if you add it to a button. It will redirect and browser it, in the app. But when you do it you header or anything else for that matter will not follow to the next screen, for the externalSite. so the way to do it is to use the iframe if you want control over the layout with an external Site.

Comment: Hi Lasse, that's what I meant above: the ExternalSite will display the page at the target URL, filling up the whole browser window after jumping. Indeed, if the target hasn't got the same header as the source, only way is to indeed framing the new content into an iframe.